# Eevee diffuse pass render bug?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, export, eevee-render-engine, render-passes

I hope this is the right place to post this.

To see the "bug", please go directly to the ***observation*** part.

**The setup**

We need to export the diffuse pass render in low resolution of a scene, like I have here.
[image: blender scene]

The scene above consists of a mesh object created by using a Skin and Subdivision modifier, and for demonstration purposes, two standard cubes of the same size, with no modifiers at all.
The two cubes are lying on top of each other, i.e. they have the exact same location.
All objects in this scene share the same Material with just a Principled BSDF shader:
[image: material]

Base Color here is:

```
R: 0.2
G: 0.4
B: 1.0
```

In the render settings, I checked Diffuse -> Color to get the respective output option on my Compositor, writing that into an EXR file.

[image: render settings]
[image]

I explicitly chose EXR here, since it allows for HDR color values greater than 1.0.

**The observation**

Now I stumpled upon the fact that in Eevee the diffuse pass seems to **add** the color values together for faces lying on top of each other (resolving "z-fighting" additively ?),
which causes for the resulting color values to be **out of SDR range** (greather than 1.0). In this case, the color values of the affected pixels are not

```
R: 0.2
G: 0.4
B: 1.0
```

as expected, but

```
R: 0.4
G: 0.8
B: 2.0
```

Now, you could circumvent this by simply telling your artists to not have any faces overlapping like this in their scenes.
The thing is, this artifact sometimes also appears (apparently) **randomly** on other objects with **no overlapping faces**, like you can see here on the skinned object, affecting only two pixels (I hope the gif plays):

[image: eevee cycles comparison]

This causes Eevee to be unuseable for us at this point.
Is this intentional behaviour or a bug within Eevee? Am I missing something obvious here?

The other solution would be to switch to Cycles for good. But we really would like to stay with Eevee, since it's way faster.

Blender Version: 2.93.1

Comment: One of the reasons, possibly the main one, that EEVEE is faster is that it's simpler, and you've just encountered an example of that simplification making EEVEE differ from Cycles.  It's not a bug, it's a feature, at least in this case.

Comment: Nevertheless I'd like to know what exactly causes the two pixels (not the cubes) to be out of SD range. For the two overlapping cubes, I get it.